# Фрейм загрузки во время работы приложения

Tags: delphi

В программе выполняется часто скачивание из интернета, само по себе не много времени занимает, но у некоторых интернет медленный. Поэтому как можно сделать чтобы при во время работы одной процедуры показывало какую нибудь загрузку, даже просто тот же фрейм с анимацией, просто чтобы пользователь видел что программа работает а не повисла.

Comment: Для этого скачивание нужно перенести в отдельный поток `TThread`.

Comment: with THTTPSend.Create do
        begin
        ProxyHost:='127.0.0.1';
        ProxyPort:='8118';
        if HTTPMethod('GET',AnsiToUtf8(URL)) then
         begin
          Jtop:=TStringStream.Create;
          Jtop.FromStream(Document)
//ниже код по работе с потоком
....

Comment: И каким способ я это делаю никак не повлияет. Если у меня скачивается 10 файлов. то как ни крути это будет все равно долго, мне то и нужно сделать что то вроде отображения ожидания. например чтоб вылез фрейм с надписью "подождите" и часами.

Comment: Используйте компоненты [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html). Они уже используют потоки, кроме того thread safe в отличие от Indy например...

Comment: Как сделать появление окна что то вроде "Подождите" с анимацией загрузки. Забейте на то как качать. вообще не важно. поверьте по другому никак не получится скачать. интернет тут такой.

Comment: Так ответили же! Перенеси скачивание в поток. Поток (TThread) - это такая штука, которая позволяет выполнять что-либо в фоновом режиме. Твои формы работают в основном потоке приложения. Если, скачивание делать в дополнительном потоке то программа зависать не будет. А @Yura Ivanov предложил не изобретать велосипед, а взять и, сразу, использовать для скачивания компоненты, в которых работа в фоновом режиме реализована "из коробки".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@Пандакун](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD)](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD) ,еще раз озвучу мысль [[@KiTE](/users/2084/kite)](/users/2084/kite):

- Показываете окно в котором будет рисоваться анимация. Можно воспользоваться обычным окном с `BorderStyle = bsNone`. Можно в открытом окне показать TPanel, поверх прочих компонентов.
- Стартуете закачку. В любой реализации закачка должна идти **отдельным** **потоком.**
- Рисуете на созданной панели/окне индикатор загрузки как вам нравится. Хоть на канву по таймеру, хоть `TProgressBar`, хоть каким-нибудь `TAnimate`.
- По окончании загрузки убираете свою панель/окно.

> И каким способ я это делаю никак не повлияет.

Отдельный поток для скачивания нужен, чтобы у вас не вешалась отрисовка окна с индикатором.

Comment: Ага это разумно а можно небольшой пример просто как скачать файл с интернете через ICS ?

Comment: Увы, с ICS не знаком.

Comment: А любым другим способом, я простто не совсем понимаю что такое "Отдельный поток"

Answer (score 0):

> > А любым другим способом, я просто не совсем понимаю что такое "Отдельный поток"

Пример работы с потоками в [этой ссылке](http://prodelphi.ucoz.ru/publ/rabota_s_potokami_v_delphi/1-1-0-16).